# store info api in next.js or browser

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, api, next.js

i want to store this ini file on server or client but can't get it to work

so i'm also happy if i can show info of ini in browser so client can copy paste info from ini.

i can't get it to work,so hopefully someone can help me out in my code.

api is tested in postman and works fine

error in browser Error serializing props returned from `getStaticProps`

```
/////////////////// api scrip audiocodes

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  var myHeaders = new Headers();
  myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Basic password");
  
  var requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: myHeaders,
    redirect: 'follow'
  };
  
  fetch("http://10.0.5.26/api/v1/files/ini", requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));

    return {
      
    }
  }
  ////////////////   start website
  const Backup = () => {
    
  



return (
    <div>
      <h1 className={styles.title}>
          refresh <a href="index1">{ result }</a>
        </h1>
      
    </div>
  );
} 
export default Backup;
```

console.log(result) with the info

```
event - compiled successfully
SerializableError: Error serializing props returned from `getStaticProps` in "/test2".
Reason: Props must be returned as a plain object from getStaticProps: `{ props: { ... } }` (received: `[object Undefined]`).
    at Object.isSerializableProps (C:\java\node\next\test\node_modules\next\dist\lib\is-serializable-props.js:19:15)
    at Object.renderToHTML (C:\java\node\next\test\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:430:97)
    at async doRender (C:\java\node\next\test\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:1127:38)
    at async C:\java\node\next\test\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:1221:28
    at async C:\java\node\next\test\node_modules\next\dist\server\response-cache.js:60:36
;**************
;** Ini File **
;**************

;Time & Date: 17/08/2021 10:14:19
;Device Up Time: 49d:22h:39m:1s
;Board: UNIVERGE BX9000
;Board Type: 72
;Serial Number: 9107130
;Software Version: 7.20A.256.721
;DSP Software Version: 5014AE3_R => 723.06
;Board IP Address: 
;Board Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
;Board Default Gateway: 1.1.1.1
;CPU: Cavium Networks Octeon V0.1 @ 500Mhz, total 2 cores, 2 cpus, 1 sockets
;Cores mapping:
;core #0, on cpu #0, on socket #0
;core #1, on cpu #1, on socket #0
;Memory: 512 MB
;Flash size: 64 MB
;Num of DSP Cores: 3
;Num of physical LAN ports: 12
;Client defaults file is being used (file length=1573)
;;;Key features:;Board Type: 72 ;IP Media: VXML ;DATA features: FireWall&VPN ;PSTN Protocols: ISDN IUA=2 CAS ;Security: IPSEC MediaEncryption StrongEncryption EncryptControlProtocol ;Channel Type: RTP DspCh=150 ;HA ;Coders: G723 G729 GSM-FR G727 G722 ;DSP Voice features: IpmDetector ;Control Protocols: MSFT FEU=50 SIP SBC=25 ;Default features:;Coders: G711 G726;

;-----  HW components -----
;
; Slot # : Module type : # of ports
;----------------------------------------------
;      1 : Empty
;      2 : Empty
;      3 : Empty
;----------------------------------------------

;USB Port 1: Empty
;USB Port 2: Empty
;----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I'd recommend you have a read through [`getStaticProps` Data Fetching](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation).

Comment: I did for the last 2 days could not fix it

Answer (score 0):

If this doesn't work add JSON.stringify(result) to where you return props

```
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  var myHeaders = new Headers();
  myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Basic password");
  
  var requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: myHeaders,
    redirect: 'follow'
  };
  
  const result = await fetch("http://10.0.5.26/api/v1/files/ini", requestOptions)
    
    return {
      props: {
         result
      }
    }
  }
  ////////////////   start website
  const Backup = ({result}) => {
    console.log(result)
  



return (
    <div>
      <h1 className={styles.title}>
          refresh <a href="index1">{ result }</a>
        </h1>
      
    </div>
  );
} 
export default Backup;
```

Comment: @clones depends and what you want to return in your return statement

Comment: i want the complete console log on website

Comment: @clones Sorry for the late response. You should put your result in a variable then stringify and pass it as a return statement, then you can access it inside your component and log it. I suppose await would be easier to use here

Comment: I have try but still stuck can you add it to my code so I can test it out thanks for your time and patience

Comment: @clones I have updated my answer check it out